# Why is my model form failing to validate and save in Django?

Tags: html, django, post, django-models, django-forms

I am sending django 2 forms in a post request 1 which works as intended and the other which fails to validate and as such is not saved.

the code for the form is here :

```
class Pick_Vulns(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ReportVuln
    fields = "__all__"
    widgets = {
    'Vuln' : Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    'Report' : HiddenInput(attrs={'Value': reportcount}),
    }
```

This form loads correctly on the page with no issues but when the post request is sent it seems to be not be accepted and fails to validate.

an example of the post request : 
[a post request to the server the first param being a csrf token the next for being the working form the last two being part of the form that does not function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tmht.png)

The code for the post request within my django view is as follows :

```
    def post(self, request):
        forminput = Reportform(request.POST or None)
        returnedvulns = Pick_Vulns(request.POST or None)


        if request.user.is_staff == True:
            if forminput.is_valid():
                forminput.save()
                if returnedvulns.is_valid():
                    returnedvulns.save()

                forminput = Reportform

                inoutform = {
                    'Reportform': forminput,
                    'reportvulns': pickvulns,
                    'ReportCount': Reportcount

                }
                return render(request, self.template_name, inoutform, )
```

the model to which the form is saved is here :

```
class ReportVuln(models.Model):
Vuln = models.ForeignKey(Vulnerability, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='Vulnerability')

Report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) # allows for the referencing of reports
```

To my memory this has been working in the past and after some minor changes it seems to have broken.

error i recieve is :

> ValueError at /reporting/Create
>
> The ReportVuln could not be created because the data didn't validate.
>
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/reporting/Create Django Version:  3.0.2
>   Exception Type:   ValueError Exception Value:
>
> The ReportVuln could not be created because the data didn't validate.

if you need any more information please ask this is a key component and needs fixing. Thank you.

Comment: what error/ validation message do you get? / what isn't working?

Comment: ValueError at /reporting/Create

The ReportVuln could not be created because the data didn't validate.

Comment: can you paste the full stack trace?

Comment: it should be here : http://dpaste.com/2D6Z6SA